# Criação de BoxPlot no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

estou fazendo algumas simulações no `R`. Ao gerar um `data.frame` e solicitar a impressão de `boxplots` com tamanho pequeno de amostra e de número de amostras o `boxplot` é gerado perfeitamente. O problema é quando aumento o tamanho amostral e o número de amostras os `boxplots` não são gerados de acordo com os dados. Para exemplificar imprimi meus dados em planilhas do excel e gerei os `boxplots` a partir destas planilhas, continuo recebendo `boxplots` errados como podem ver abaixo. Não consigo encontrar o problema!

```
##Box-Plot dos valores simulados dos parâmetros.

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df1 <- read.csv(url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/58046aff/d1.csv"), sep = ";")
attach(df1)
df1$parametros <- factor(df1$parametros,
                         levels = c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0","beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho"), ordered = TRUE)

g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = parametros,y = val_Sim)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

df2 <- read.csv(url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/58046aff/d2.csv"), sep = ";")

attach(df2)
df2$parametros <- factor(df2$parametros,
                         levels = c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2"), ordered = TRUE)


g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


df3 <- read.csv(url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/58046aff/d3.csv"), sep = ";")
attach(df3)
df3$parametros <- factor(df3$parametros,
                         levels = c("beta0","beta1","beta2"), ordered = TRUE)

g3 <- ggplot(df3, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


df4 <- read.csv(url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/58046aff/d4.csv"), sep = ";")
attach(df4)
df4$parametros <- factor(df4$parametros,
                         levels = c("phi1", "rho"), ordered = TRUE)



g4 <- ggplot(df4, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.25),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(g1,g2, g3, g4)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por algum motivo que desconheço, os teus arquivos `df2`, `df3` e `df4` estão errados. Veja, por exemplo, o que ocorre quando calculo a mediana de cada grupo, utilizando `df1`, `df2_original` (que é o teu `df2`) e `df2_correto` (que eu criei a partir do `df1`, selecionando apenas as linhas com valores de gamma):

```
df1 <- read.csv(url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/58046aff/d1.csv"), sep = ";")
df1 %>% 
  group_by(parametros) %>% 
  summarise(mediana = median(val_Sim, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  parametros   mediana
      <fctr>     <dbl>
1      beta0 0.9406746
2      beta1 0.8604181
3      beta2 0.2352544
4     gamma0 0.7085335
5     gamma1 0.8904442
6     gamma2 0.9441261
7       phi1 0.2305419
8        rho 0.2301348
df2_original <- read.csv(url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/58046aff/d2.csv"), sep = ";")
df2_original %>% 
  group_by(parametros) %>% 
  summarise(mediana = median(val_Sim, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  parametros   mediana
      <fctr>     <dbl>
1     gamma0 0.7068794
2     gamma1 0.9087855
3     gamma2 0.8771044
df2_correto <- filter(df1, parametros=="gamma0" | parametros=="gamma1" | 
  parametros=="gamma2")
df2_correto %>% 
  group_by(parametros) %>% 
  summarise(mediana = median(val_Sim, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  parametros   mediana
      <fctr>     <dbl>
1     gamma0 0.7085335
2     gamma1 0.8904442
3     gamma2 0.9441261
```

Perceba que as medianas de `df2_correto` são idênticas às de `df1`. Elas estão, inclusive, em ordem crescente, como o boxplot com todos os parâmetros sugere. Por isso, desconfio que houve algum erro na criação dos teus subsets originais, ou seja, os arquivos `df2.csv`, `df3.csv` e `df4.csv` estão com algum problema.

Além disso, note que a sintaxe da função `filter` é bastante simples. Foi trivial selecionar as linhas que me interessavam para criar o `df2` apenas com os valores de `gamma0`, `gamma1` e `gamma2`. Eu não precisei criar arquivos separados para isto, deixando o código um pouco mais organizado e mais fácil de debugar.

Portanto, agindo assim consegui obter os gráficos desejados sem precisar apelar para arquivos .csv além do arquivo original `d1.csv`. Para isto, utilizei mais algumas vezes a função `filter` do pacote `dplyr`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(gridExtra)

df1 <- read.csv(url("https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/58046aff/d1.csv"), sep = ";")

df1$parametros <- factor(df1$parametros,
                         levels = c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0","beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho"), ordered = TRUE)

g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = parametros,y = val_Sim)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

df2_correto <- filter(df1, parametros=="gamma0" | parametros=="gamma1" | 
  parametros=="gamma2")

g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = parametros,y = val_Sim)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

df3 <- filter(df1, parametros=="beta0" | parametros=="beta1" | parametros=="beta2")

g3 <- ggplot(df3, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


df4 <- filter(df1, parametros=="phi1" | parametros=="rho")

g4 <- ggplot(df4, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") +   xlab("Parâmetros") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.25),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

grid.arrange(g1,g2, g3, g4)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, perceba que não foi preciso reordenar os níveis dos `parametros` para cada novo `df`, pois o data frame original já os tinha ordenado. E, por fim, não é necessário usar `attach`, que é uma função redundante devido à sintaxe do `ggplot` e `dplyr`.

Comment: Obrigado @MarcusNunes, também não entendo o motivo do erro dos arquivos df2, df3 e df4, pois esses foram gerados a partir dos mesmos dados que a df1. De qualquer forma, sua ajuda foi muito proveitosa! Muito obrigado por sua disponibilidade!